# How to create a child exe,proccess with mfc?

Tags: mfc, parent-child, exe

I want to call a process though mfc but i need that new exe must pretend like a child dialog. So if the new exe won't close, user shouldn't reach main process (dialog) is it possible?

Comment: If I understand what you mean, you can simply spawn a new process and close the current (parent) process

Comment: No after user finished her work on new exe, she could turn the first mfc exe.

Comment: So you want to make maybe the new process dialog modal and to take all screen?

Comment: I only want it to related to my exe , not block all of other things with full screen , always top stuff. but not bad idea thanks anyway.

Comment: i think you want do finish work on child process then go parent dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is. when you open new process,you have to do wait user till closed child process then you have to use WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

following code...

```
if( !CreateProcess( NULL, // No module name (use command line).
    exePath,      // Command line.
    NULL,// Process handle not inheritable.
    NULL,                 // Thread handle not inheritable.
    FALSE,                // Set handle inheritance to FALSE.
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,// No creation flags.
    NULL,                 // Use parent's environment block.
    NULL,                 // Use parent's starting directory.
    &si,                  // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure.
    &pi )                 // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure.
    )
{
    cout << "Unable to create\n";}
    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );

    return false;

}

    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );// wait user till close exe(after close child process then go parent process)
return true;

// Close process and thread handles.
CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be easily done using OLE-Automation / COM. With an out of process Server you have an procdeual Interface and a second process...

Comment: is it possible at mfc application in vs2003?